# Is there a van Laarhoven optic based on the Monad typeclass?

Tags: haskell, lenses, haskell-optics

As I understand it, each van Laarhoven optic type can be defined by a constraint on a type constructor:

```hs
type Lens      s t a b = forall f. Functor f     => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
type Traversal s t a b = forall f. Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
-- etc.
```

If we choose `Monad` as the constraint, does it form some kind of "optic" in a meaningful way?

```hs
type Something s t a b = forall f. Monad f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
```

My intuition is that the `Monad` constraint might be too restrictive to get any value out of a structure like this: since the `Const` functor is not a `Monad`, we can't do the trick of specializing `f` to `Const` in order to derive a `view`-like function. Still, we can do *some* things with this `Something` type; it's just not clear to me if we can do anything particularly useful with it.

The reason I'm curious is because the type of a van Laarhoven optic is suspiciously similar to the type of a function that modifies a "mutable reference" type like `IORef`. For example, we can easily implement

```hs
modifyIORefM :: MonadIO m => IORef a -> (a -> m a) -> () -> m ()
```

which, when partially-applied to an `IORef`, has the shape

```hs
type SomethingIO s t a b = forall f. MonadIO f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
```

where `a = b` and `s = t = ()`. I'm not sure whether this is a meaningful or meaningless coincidence.

Comment: There's MLens, but after a quick scan i don't think that's what you had in mind.

Comment: Was also wondering about this for long!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Practically speaking, such an optic is a slightly inconvenient `Traversal`.

That's because, practically speaking, we use a `Traversal`:

```
type Traversal s t a b = forall f. (Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> (s -> f t)
```

for two things.  Getting a list of `a`s from an `s`, which we can do with the `Const` functor:

```
toListOf :: Traversal s t a b -> s -> [a]
toListOf t = getConst . t (Const . (:[]))
```

and replacing the `a`s with `b`s to turn the `s` into a `t`.  One method is to use the `State` functor, and ignoring issues with matching the counts of `a`s and `b`s, we have:

```
setListOf :: Traversal s t a b -> [b] -> s -> t
setListOf t bs s = evalState (t (\a -> state (\(b:bs) -> (b, bs))) s) bs
```

If we instead have an optic using a `Monad` constraint:

```
type TraversalM s t a b = forall f. (Monad f) => (a -> f b) -> (s -> f t)
```

we can still perform these two operations.  Since `State` is a monad, the `setListOf` operation can use the same implementation:

```
setListOfM :: Traversal s t a b -> [b] -> s -> t
setListOfM t bs s = evalState (t (\a -> state (\(b:bs) -> (b, bs))) s) bs
```

For `toListOf`, there's no `Monad` instance for `Const [a]`, but we can use a `Writer` monad to extract the `a` values, as long as we have a dummy `b` value to make the type checker happy:

```
toListOfM :: TraversalM s t a b -> b -> s -> [a]
toListOfM t dummy_b s = execWriter (t (\a -> tell [a] >> pure dummy_b) s)
```

or, since Haskell has bottom:

```
toListOfM' :: TraversalM s t a b -> s -> [a]
toListOfM' t s = execWriter (t (\a -> tell [a] >> pure undefined) s)
```

Self-contained code:

```
import Data.Functor.Const
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Writer

type Traversal s t a b = forall f. (Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> (s -> f t)

toListOf :: Traversal s t a b -> s -> [a]
toListOf t = getConst . t (Const . (:[]))

setListOf :: Traversal s t a b -> [b] -> s -> t
setListOf t bs s = evalState (t (\a -> state (\(b:bs) -> (b, bs))) s) bs

type TraversalM s t a b = forall f. (Monad f) => (a -> f b) -> (s -> f t)

toListOfM :: TraversalM s t a b -> b -> s -> [a]
toListOfM t dummy_b s = execWriter (t (\a -> tell [a] >> pure dummy_b) s)

toListOfM' :: TraversalM s t a b -> s -> [a]
toListOfM' t s = execWriter (t (\a -> tell [a] >> pure undefined) s)

setListOfM :: TraversalM s t a b -> [b] -> s -> t
setListOfM t bs s = evalState (t (\a -> state (\(b:bs) -> (b, bs))) s) bs

listItems :: Traversal [a] [b] a b
listItems = traverse

listItemsM :: TraversalM [a] [b] a b
listItemsM = mapM

main = do
  -- as a getter
  print $ toListOf listItems [1,2,3]
  print $ toListOfM listItemsM 99 [1,2,3]  -- dummy value
  print $ toListOfM' listItemsM [1,2,3]    -- use undefined
  -- as a setter
  print $ setListOf listItems [4,5,6] [1,2,3]
  print $ setListOfM listItemsM [4,5,6] [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Interesting! I think that answers my question. It seems unlikely that `TraversalM` and `Traversal` would be *isomorphic*, so I wonder if there are any `TraversalM`s that can't be made into `Traversal`s?